# Title page does not appear in my thesis

Tags: titles

Hi I was using an old version (2005) of `Tex` before this. I updated to the latest `Texmaker` yesterday and try to compile my thesis but somehow the `PDF` file generated does not contain my title page. I know this question have been asked and I have read other post related to my issue here, and even played around with the coding but the title page still doe not appear. Here is the coding for title page :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\setlength{\textwidth}{16cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xparse,nameref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[nokeyprefix]{refstyle}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumerate}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\lcm}{lcm}
\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\setlength\defaultaddspace{2ex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[figuresleft]{rotating}
\usepackage{rotating}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\swb{{\scriptstyle\Box}} % "small white box"
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{upgreek} %use uptau greek letter
\usepackage{comment} %choose parts not to compile
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{mynode/.style={fill=white,text=black,font=\tiny,inner sep=1pt}}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
\newenvironment{numberlists}[1][3\parindent] %for long numberlist command
 {\begin{list}{}{%
   \leftmargin=#1\relax
   \rightmargin=\leftmargin
   \itemsep=\jot
   \parsep=0pt
   \partopsep=0pt
   \labelsep=0pt}}
 {\end{list}}
\newcommand\numlist[2]{%
  \item[]\makebox[0pt][r]{$#1=\lbrack$}%
  \begingroup
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`,\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\mathcomma\penalty0 }%
  \mathcode`,="8000
  \thinmuskip=6mu plus 6mu minus 2mu
  $#2\rbrack$%
  \endgroup
}
\mathchardef\mathcomma=\mathcode`, %end of numberlist command
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-1in}   \setlength{\evensidemargin}{-1in}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{25mm}\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{20mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{40pt} \setlength{\marginparsep}{10pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-5mm}      \setlength{\headsep}{0.5in}
\setlength{\textheight}{227mm}    \setlength{\textwidth}{165mm}
\renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.8} %   Default = 0.5
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}

\allowdisplaybreaks % allow page breaks
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.70\textwidth]{logo} \\[2cm]

{ \large \bfseries Perfect Triangles : Rational points on Elliptic Curves }\\
Shahrina Ismail \\
\{Candidate's academic degrees\} \\[7cm]
{\em A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy at\\
The University of Queensland in 2016} \\
School of Mathematics and Physics

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\begin{abstract}
here...
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\listoftables

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{chapters/Introduction}

\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Background and Methodology}\label{chap:2}
\input{chapters/chapter2}


\onehalfspacing
\chapter{Values of $\delta(\mu)$}\label{chap:3}
\input{chapters/chapter3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code (without the line for the logo) compiles fine for me if I add `\documentclass{report}`, for example, so I'd suggest the problem lies in code you haven't posted. A MWE would help.

Comment: @GarethWalker.. Hi I have edited my coding to include the main .tex coding. please ignore the humongous usepackages.  I believe (from my reading on posts related to my issue here) that the problem should be around \begin{titlepage} in Texmaker. I have tried to play around with it but the title page still refuse to appear.. My PDF file starts with abstract instead of the title page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of the very first page not appearing appears to be caused by the presence of the following instruction, located near the very end of the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
```

What is the purpose of this instruction? If you comment it out (or delete it outright...), the title page material shows up without a problem.

I can't help but comment that the document preamble is a mess. Sorry for having to be so blunt and direct, but there's no way to sugarcoat it. Some packages are loaded more than once, the ordering in which some of the packages are loaded is potentially problematic (e.g., `hyperref` and `cleveref` should be loaded toward the end of the preamble), some packages are in conflict with each other (e.g., load `enumerate` or `enumitem`, *but not both*), some setup instructions are repeated or redundant (e.g., why are there 3 instructions to set the value of `\oddsidemargin`?), still other setup instructions could (and probably should) be streamlined considerably, and the purpose of some of the instructions -- such as the one shown above -- is a mystery, to put it politely. In sum, you may want to make an effort to get a handle on the preamble. You'll experience far fewer surprises of the type that prompted you to post this query to begin with.

Comment: The purpose of \AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}} was actually recommended by one of the user when I was using the old latex version because I had an empty first page, and the title page appeared on the second page which I was not sure of the reason behind it. But I guess now that I am using the latest Texmaker version, the problem was solved and I did not need that instruction anymore. Thank you so much for pointing that out. My PDF file now is fine with the title page appearing as usual.

Comment: Also thank you for pointing out the preamble. I know I really have to sit down and look through the preamble and fix the mess.. some of the usepackage appear twice.. And some of them I do not even need.. Thank you fpr pointing that out too. I appreciate it.